# Money Counting Bug Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, currency

I'm on Unity using c# scripts that count money and add a suffix after it when needed. For some obscure reasons, it stops at 2.1B, switch to -2.1B and then doesn't change until 0.0T, which also doesn't change value, and it go like this for every suffix. Here is my code:

```
    void Update(){
{
    pointIncreasedPerSecond = 10.0f * k;
    scoreAmount += pointIncreasedPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    if(scoreAmount < 999f){
    scoreTime.text =  "$ " + (int)scoreAmount;
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999f && scoreAmount < 999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000f).ToString("F1") + "K";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000f).ToString("F1") + "M";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000f).ToString("F1") + "B";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "T";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "Qd";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "Qn";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "Sx";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "Sp";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "O";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "N";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 999999999999999999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 999999999999999999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "$" + ((int)scoreAmount / 1000000000000000000000000000000000f).ToString("F1") + "D";
    }
    if(scoreAmount > 99999999999999999999999999999999999f && scoreAmount < 99999999999999999999999999999999999999f){
        scoreTime.text = "Trouve un taff";
    }
}
```

Comment: you just overflow your int datatype, use ulong if you dont need decimals for example

Comment: Hi there. What you've encountered is an integer overflow. You need a different way of representing the numbers. Int cannot store such a big numer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Thanks a lot you are saving me hours of wrong way researches.

Comment: => [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) and [`BigRational`](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bcl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your score amount is propably an Int32 its reach is of 2,147,483,647 so around 2.1 Billion other type have higher cap like float or decimal. I recommend using a long if you want to stay in integer or a decimal if you want the highest number possible

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer if you used it? I'm trying to build up an account. @Whitheaven

Comment: done it ;) thanks again, I finally decided to use float instead of int.

Comment: `float` has the same issue only later see [`float.MaxValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.maxvalue) ... You might rather want to use `double` or `decimal` see [Floating point numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) ... or if you want to go "infinite" and fancy have a look at [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) and [`BigRational`](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bcl)